# Redux-form async validation returning undefined for fields in asyncBlurFields

Tags: react-native, redux-form, react-redux-form

My code is similar to [this example](http://redux-form.com/6.7.0/examples/asyncValidation/) presented in the doc. However, I've noticed that the `asyncValidate` function receives undefined for any field specified in the `asyncBlurFields` array as soon as I unFocus from that field. However, it returns the right values when I submit the form or unFocus from a different field.

For example, if I have `asyncBlurFields: ['username', 'firstname']` and there's a value in both fields, I'll see `username` as undefined in the values passed to `asyncValidate`when I unFocus from `username` but the value of `firstname` will be present. If I then unFocus from `firstname`, the value of `firstname` will now be undefined while that of `username` will be present. Both values will be present when I submit the form. It seems similar to the question raised in [issue #1834](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/1834). However, I don't understand the response given in that issue. Could someone please help me with an example or further explanation.

I'm using version 7.0.1 of redux-form and version 0.45.1 of react-native.

Answer (score 2):

I've figured it out. Here's what my `renderInput()` now looks like. The important thing here is the line with `onBlur=...`

```
renderInput({
    input,
    label,
    type,
    meta: { asyncValidating, touched, error, active }
  }) {
  return (
    <Item>
      <Input
        placeholder={label}
        {...input}
        type={type}
        onBlur={() => input.onBlur(input.value)}
      />
    </Item>
  );
}
```

Comment: This should have been fine without the `onBlur` prop, unless you were previously overriding `onBlur` with something else.